# c++ compiling problem

Tags: c++, compilation

I'm trying to compile a c++ program, which is something I didn't do for a long time...

What I'm trying is:

```
g++ -c A.cpp  -o A.o

g++ -c dir/B.h -o B.o
```

which seem to work, and then I try:

```
g++ A.o B.o -o A -lX11 -lpthread
```

and get:

> B.o: file not recognized: File format
>   not recognized
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

What is the problem?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 8):

Omit the -o argument when you compile b.h, and you will likely see 
that g++ creates a file named b.h.gch rather than b.o.  That file
is a "pre-compiled header file".  By renaming in b.o, you are
lying to the subsequent invocation of g++ about the contents
of the file.  If b.h is a header file, then you should include
it in a.cpp.  If b.h contains function definitions, you should
rename it b.cpp.

Answer (score 3):

```
g++ -c dir/B.h -o B.o
```

Why are you compiling a header file?

I assume A.cpp includes dir/B.h - so you don't need a separate compiler invocation to compile the header.

Answer (score 0):

You're compiling a header file.  No good can come of that.  :-)

Comment: Precompiled headers are very useful in C++ projects, as they can speed-up the compilation significantly, especially when using big header-only libraries like Boost.